# How to insert and delete new lines with LYNX?

Tags: lynx

I am editing a text field with `lynx`, how can I insert a new line before another line or delete a line? I tried hitting insert and all that stuff. I looked at the `man` pages and didn't find anything.

Comment: Are you talking about `lynx` the terminal webbrowsser ? I guess it doesn't have an internal editor, and might launch and external command configured either by shell variable or lynx configuration. 
If so, the manual of the editor might be ressourcefull

Comment: Yes, `lynx` the terminal web browser. I don't know how it works, I just use it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an editor on the command line.

```
-editor=EDITOR

enable external editing, using the specified EDITOR. (vi, ed, emacs, etc.)
```

You can start the external editor with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>

Further information can be found here:

http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/keystrokes/edit_help.html

Answer (score 2):

If you type `o` inside `lynx` you will open the option menu. 
Inside you will find the editor field, which specifies which external editor `lynx` will launch when requested.

So the displayed value is the currently editor you are using (may be vim/emacs/nano).

Then you have two options :

- learn how to use this editor
- set the editor value to one you already know.

Answer (score 0):

Lynx has two sets of key bindings:

- There are the normal command-bindings which you can see with the `k` (or `K`) key (see [documentation](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/keystrokes/keystroke_help.html)).
- there are also the "line edit" bindings (see [documentation](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/keystrokes/edit_help.html)).  Those apply to text-fields.  However, if you have configured an external editor using the Options menu, then `^Xe` (<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>) runs the editor on the currently selected text field.

You may notice in the listing from `k` that it is bound to `KEYMAP`.  Likewise you could configure Lynx to bind a key to the `EDITMAP` listing, showing the bindings in use.